# How do I add a custom string to symfony2 path?

Tags: twig, symfony-2.1

I have a custom page in /web/blog and I want to create a link to forward to it. How can I do this ? I have tried many things but none of them works, like

```
<a href="{{ path('homepage') | '/blog' }}" title="" >{{ 'menu.blog'|trans }}</a>
```

or

```
<a href="{{ path('homepage') }}/blog" title="" >{{ 'menu.blog'|trans }}</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but the right answer is :

```
<a href="{{ path('homepage') }}{{ 'blog' }}">
```

Comment: Heh... That's was much simpler than I thought! Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

i use

```
<a href="{{ path('homepage')}}/{{blog}} title="">
```

@Adam solution is right